# Не хватает inline кнопки telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Итак, я написал легкого бота который поможет в учебе python (самое легкое переменные, списки и т.д.) но бот не добавляет кнопку списки вот скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код: https://pastebin.com/m3KnNehd

Comment: `inline_menu.add(variables, loops, functions)` замените на `inline_menu.add(variables, loops, functions, lists)`